# Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-dusk

I tried laravel dusk on Laravel Framework 5.5.38 by following this https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/dusk

My environment is on windows WSL running Ubuntu 16.04

I tried this

1. composer require --dev laravel/dusk:"^2.0"
2. php artisan dusk:install
3. php artisan dusk

and I got this on the last one

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"binary":"","args":["--disable-gpu","--headless"]}}}

Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused
```

my url on local is `http://crateclub.test`

Does anyone encounter similar to this?

Comment: Is the port up? Just to be sure.

Comment: I don't know, how to check that?

Comment: for windows use `netstat -an`, for linux it's `netstat -l`. See if the port is listed there. If it is ilisted, disable firewall and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error while attempting to run [php-webdriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) with Windows WSL running Ubuntu inside of a VS Code terminal.

My fix was to switch my execution environment to [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) (in external [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/)) and everything started working.  You may need to re-install some tools such as PHP CLI and Composer, but this worked for me.